# "Cannot convert char* to char(*)[95]" error

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I have code for using an array to create an ASCII table. I am having trouble compiling the code due to errors:

> cannot convert 'char*' to char(*)[95] for argument '1' to void buildTable(char (8)[95], int)

and

> cannot convert std::ofstream to char(*)[95] for argument '1' to 'void printTable(char(8)[95], int)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 

int main () {
    const int MAX_SIZE = 95;
    char symbols[MAX_SIZE];
    int values[MAX_SiZE], int values);
    void buildTable (char [][MAX_SIZE], int values);
    void printTable (char [][MAX_SIZE], int values);
    void output(std::fstream, std::string, double); 

    std::string line;

    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("ascii.log");
    if(outputFile.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Error opening file. \n";
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        buildTable (symbols, values, MAX_SIZE);
        printTable (outputFile, symbols, values, MAX_SIZE);
    }
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For your next question, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), abnd learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The variable `symbols` is an array of `char`. It will decay to a pointer to its first element, `&symbols[0]`, which will be of type `char*`.

The functions you declare takes its first parameter as a pointer to an array of `char`. A pointer to an array of `char` is very different from a pointer to `char`.

The solution is to make the function take the same data-type as you pass, i.e. a pointer to `char`, `char*`.

You also have multiple other problems. For example the functions you declare (`buildTable` and `printTable`) are currently declared to that this wrong argument as the first argument, and then `int` value as second argument. But that's not how you call those functions. You need to declare the functions with their actual arguments, and call them as declared.

---

On a related note: Since you program in C++ please don't use character arrays for strings, use `std::string` instead. It will save you a lot in the long run.

Comment: Thank you. I am very new to coding. For clarification, are you saying that instead of using char, i should use char*?

Comment: Originally instead of int main() i had int main(int argc, char * argv[])

Comment: @KAJ Instead of `char [][MAX_SIZE]` you should have `char*`.

Comment: Hmm just tried that and I’m getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: @KAJ Take a look at the declarations of the functions you have. Then take a look at how you call them. Does it match?

Comment: My declarations : const int MAX_SIZE = 95 ; char symbols [MAX_SIZE]; int values[MAX_SIZE];

Comment: How i call: void buildTable (char*, int values);

Comment: and buildTable (symbols, values, MAX_SIZE};

Comment: Similar to my code posted in the question but changed to char*

Comment: @KAJ Yes, you declare that the function takes two arguments, and then you call it with *three*. That's not valid. And furthermore the second argument doesn't match as well.

Comment: @KAJ No I'm telling you to *think* a little. How are the functions actually *defined*? What arguments do they *really* take? What arguments do you *need* to pass? Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or hand-holding site. I'm sorry if I'm sounding rude, but you do need to be able to think a little for yourself.